# Cannot install the m2e connector for build-helper-maven-plugin in eclipse photon

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse

I'm trying to install the m2e connector for build-helper-maven-plugin in eclipse photon using the following steps

Help-->install new sofware--the use the folowing link: https://repository.sonatype.org/content/repositories/forge-sites/m2e-extras/0.15.0/N/0.15.0.201109282249/

but the installation always faill with the following error

[image]

Please, do somebody know the right way to install this plugin in Eclipse Photon?

Comment: That code seems to be from 2011 whereas Eclipse Photon is from 2018. What you are trying to install is probably too old and not compatible.

Comment: Thanks for your answers greg. Please do you have any idea about how I can install this plugin in eclipse photon?